# sql_srv query using in AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs

So, here I have a regular php query to database:

```
$sql="SELECT LastName, FirstName FROM Students";
$result=sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
```

What do i have to do to be able to use the result of query in AngularJS?

```
   <tr data-ng-repeat="x in <!--DESIRED OBJECT-->">
        <td>{{ x.LastName }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.FirstName }}</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Echo the data as json on server side, then [use a service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) to get data from the server side into the client side (angular)

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer after consulting a friend of mine:

First, I had to store the result of query in array, like this:

```
$json=array();
do {
        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $json[] = $row;
        }
} while ( sqlsrv_next_result($result) );
```

Then, I had to encode array as a JSON (thus the name of array):

```
$encoded=json_encode($json, true);
```

After that, a controller script was needed:

```
    <script>
        function marksCtrl($scope) {
            $scope.list=<?php echo $encoded ?>;
    }
    </script>
```

And then I was free to use it in Angular way:

```
   <table data-ng-app="" ng-controller="marksCtrl">
        <tr data-ng-repeat="x in list">
             <td>{{ x.LastName }}</td>
             <td>{{ x.FirstName }}</td>
        </tr>
   </table>
```